# How to find constraints of optimization problem using first order condition?

Tags: optimization

I am studying past exam answers for a remote econ math exam, but I don't understand the given solution for this question:

> $$
> \begin{array}{ll}
> \text{Maximize}& z(x,y) = y e^{5x} \\
> \text{Subject to}& ax + by = 8 \\
> \text{Where} & x\geq 0~\text{and}~ y \geq 0
> \end{array} 
> $$
> The maximum location of this problem is $(x,y) = \left(\frac{1}{5}, 1\right)$. Determine $a$ and $b$.

[solution to problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKqkt.png)

In the solution they use "first order condition"":

$5y\cdot e^{5x} / e^{5x} = a/b$

$ax + by = 9$

To come to $5y = a/b$

and $ax + by = 8$, see image.

But I don't understand where this "first order condition" comes from and how they come to these conclusions, could somebody explain it to me please? I searched online but can't find anything.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Form the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda) = y e^{5x}-\lambda(a x+b y -8)
$$

then from the stationary conditions $\nabla L = \cases{5ye^{5x}-\lambda a = 0\\ e^{5x} - \lambda b = 0\\ a x+b y -8 = 0}$

now eliminating $\lambda$ we obtain

$$
\lambda = \frac{5ye^{5x}}{a} = \frac{e^{5x}}{b}\Rightarrow 5y = \frac ab
$$